# Display live preview of page on hover in WP admin using ACF relationship field

Tags: ajax, wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to adapt the *Advanced Custom Fields* relationship functionality in WordPress so that instead of just displaying a thumbnail it shows the live page preview on hover? I believe this would require some custom AJAX.

Here is the *Advanced Custom Fields* field in question...
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/acf5-whats-new-relationship.png

If no to the above is it possible to add a preview page link somewhere so that you can preview the page in a new tab or window before linking it to the page?

If this can't be done with *Advanced Custom Fields* can it be done at all and how?

The reason for this functionality is that a the user will require the ability to create a page made up of custom post types. the number of posts that they can choose form will be large so a preview will be required as the choice will be based on visual aspect rather than text.

Currently Advance Custom Fields uses the featured image as a thumbnail image so i'm wondering if a live preview image can be generated and used as the featured image?

Comment: I think I saw one question about how to do a thumbnail of a page...

Comment: this would be a cool feature, any ideas if there was a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [meta box that contains an iframe](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140885/can-i-display-the-widget-admin-in-the-page-admin/141533#141533). Then add a custom script to the page, like [this plugin](https://github.com/mrwweb/ACF-Repeater-Collapser/blob/master/acf_repeater_collapser.php), and listen to modifications on ACF's Relationship object. The object contains the post ID and that will be used to change the URL source of the iframe, `http://example.com/?post=OBJECT-ID`.

I tested in the console and works ok:

```
$('div.relationship_left ul.bl.relationship_list li a').mouseenter(function(){ 
    var the_id = $(this).data('post_id');
    console.log( the_id );
});
```

The response time may not be ideal, loading a page takes longer than moving a mouse...

Maybe a better result can be achieved using Ajax and pulling just the post object from the database, and with that fill your custom meta box with a `<div>` containing `post_title` + `post_content`.

---

<sup><sub>[follow-up]</sub></sup> I went ahead and copy pasted a proof of concept with Ajax, an iframe is too heavy.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Preview ACF relationships
 * Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/26061769/1287812
 * Version:     1.0
 * Author:      brasofilo 
 */

Class SO_26061769 {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'setup' ) );
    }

    function setup() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_live_preview', array( $this, 'live_preview' ) ); 
    }

    public function meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'preview_metabox', 'Preview ACF relationship', array( $this, 'mb_preview' ), 'post' );
    }

    function mb_preview() { 
    ?>
        <h2>preview</h2>
        <div id="post-ajax-preview">...</div>
        <style>
        #post-ajax-preview img { max-width:50px; max-height:50px; width: auto; height: auto; } 
        #post-ajax-preview { height: 200px; overflow:hidden;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var myAjax = {
            'url': '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>',
            'nonce': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "live_preview_nonce" ); ?>'
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $(document). on( 'mouseenter', 'div.relationship_left ul.bl.relationship_list li a', function(){ 
                var data = {
                    action: 'live_preview',
                    nonce: myAjax.nonce,
                    post_id: $(this).data('post_id')
                };
                $.post( myAjax.url, data, function( response ) {
                    var $html = '<h3>' + response.data.post_title + '</h3><p>' + response.data.post_content + '</p>';
                    $('#post-ajax-preview').html( $html );
                });
            }); 
        });             
        </script>
    <?php
    }

    public function live_preview() {
        check_ajax_referer( 'live_preview_nonce', 'nonce' );
        if( isset ( $_POST['post_id'] ) )
            $post = get_post( (int) $_POST['post_id'] );

        if( !empty( $post ) ) {
            $post->post_content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); // do shortcodes
            wp_send_json_success( $post );
        }
        else
            wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => 'No data.' ) );
    }
}
$SO26061769 = new SO_26061769;
```

This is the result. But note that I moved the meta box content *by hand*, integrating it with ACF, manipulating the DOM with the browser inspector, but that's easily done with jQuery.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this Brasofilo :) i'm going to try and get my head around this and implement it now. I'll let you know how i get on, thanks again :)

Comment: Is there a specific file that I need to paste this code into or do I need to create a new file within the ACF pro plugin folder?

Comment: See [*Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've created and activated the plugin but nothing seems to have happened. I turned off other plugins to see if it could be a conflict but still doesn't work. Also I added a ?> to the end of the code as it looks like the php tag needed closing but hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Is the post type correct? Does the meta box appears? Make sure the *mouseenter* event is pointing to the right ACF element: `'div.relationship_left ul.bl.relationship_list li a'`

Comment: The post type is correct and the meta box does appear. i've replaced the mouseenter with `.acf-relationship .list ul .acf-rel-item'` and also tried `.acf-relationship .acf-rel-item .thumbnail` but still no success.

Comment: Here's how I located ACF element: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VjoWs.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/OThPM.png

Comment: OK so i've changed the mouse event to `.acf-relationship .choices` , then tried '.acf-relationship .list ul .acf-rel-item'' but still no success. See screenshots here http://imgur.com/gallery/GgG9T/new

Comment: you said you moved the meta box content by hand, i'm not sure what you mean by this but as i haven't done this i'm wondering if this has anything to do with it not working? also i dont have the empty preview space to the right of the meta box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62106/discussion-between-brasofilo-and-amesey).

Comment: Hi brasofilo... did you have any further thoughts on my issue with the preview roll over

Comment: No, Amesey, I didn't. There's nothing else I can do without direct hands-on involvement. You have all the necessary elements to solve this alone, you're just missing the right jQuery selectors...